# Is it possible to make a Plugin loader in Python?

Tags: python, plugins, loader

i wanted to make an simple application to read all Files inside of a Folder and import the code inside of the files, i don´t realy know how to do that so i would really be happy, if someone could say me how to do that!

My code:

```
import os
plugins = os.walk('assets/plugins')
for plugin in plugins:
    pluginloader = open(f'{plugin}.py', 'w')
    pluginloader.write(f'from {plugin} import *')
    from pluginloader import *
```

LG: Luca!

Comment: A Google search for "python plugin loader" gave me a bunch of hits. Do any of them solve your problem?

Comment: @joanis thx, but i already searched on google